# NTBackup Error: C: is not a valid drive

Tags: ntbackup

I'm trying to use NtBackup to back up the C: Drive on a Microsoft Windows Small Business Server 2003 machine and get the following error in the log file:

> Backup Status Operation: Backup Active
>   backup destination: 4mm DDS Media
>   name: "Media created 04/02/2011 at
>   21:56"
>
> Error: The device reported an error on
>   a request to read data from media.
>   Error reported: Invalid command. There
>   may be a hardware or media problem.
>   Please check the system event log for
>   relevant failures.
>
> Error: C: is not a valid drive, or you
>   do not have access.
>
> ---
>
> The operation did not successfully
>   complete.
>
> ---

I'm using a brand new SATA Quantum Dat-72 drive with a brand new tape (tried a couple of tapes).

I carry out the following:

1. Open NTBackup
2. Select Backup Tab
3. Tick the box next to C:
4. Ensure Destination is 4mm DDS
5. Media is set to New
6. Press Start Backup
7. Choose Replace the data on the media and press Start Backup
8. NTBackup tries to mount the media
9. Error Message shows:

> The device reported an error on a request to read data from media. Error reported: INvalid command. There may be a hardware or media problem. Please check the system event log for relevant failures.

On checking the log I find the following:

> Event Type:   Information
>
> Event Source: NTBackup
>
> Event Category:   None
>
> Event ID: 8018
>
> Date:     04/02/2011
>
> Time:     22:02:02
>
> User:     N/A
>
> Computer: SERVER
>
> Description:
>
> Begin Operation
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

and then;

> Event Type:   Information
>
> Event Source: NTBackup
>
> Event Category:   None
>
> Event ID: 8019
>
> Date:     04/02/2011
>
> Time:     22:02:59
>
> User:     N/A
>
> Computer: SERVER
>
> Description:
>
> End Operation:
>
> The operation was successfully completed.
>
> Consult the backup report for more details.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: Couple of things... Is the user you're running it as a member of the Backup Operators group? What about volume shadow copy - is that in use, and are there any errors in the event log? Also, have you tried backing up to a .bkf file as well?

Comment: Hey, No errors in the event log at all - only information items which I put below to how start/end operation. User is the 'Administrator' who is a member of Administrators, Backup Operators, Domain Admins, Domain Users, Enterprise Admins, Group Policy Creator, Mobile Users, Schema Admins. Tried backing up to a .bkf and it worked perfectly. Volume shadow copy is in use

Comment: @Chris Not related to the backup issue directly but did you put the admin account into the enterprise and schema admins groups as a troubleshooting step? Or is it normally like that :-O - imho you only need those roles when making changes that require them, and its good practice and mistake avoidance to stay out of them otherwise. You should only need to be a backup operator for NTBackup if I remember rightly. Which brings us on to: have you set custom ACLs on that drive? Applied a security template to the system that might have changed the ACLs?

Comment: @Robert The account I'm using was configured like that by default :) No custom ACLs that I know of either. Went with a fairly standard setup initially to get the basics right before locking things down

Comment: Just to follow up on this. I installed Symantec Backup Exec and the tape drive is now working perfectly. Presumably there is something odd going on with NTBackup on this machine, but no idea what.